# Vue component select some options by default

Tags: laravel, gulp, elixir, vue.js

**UPDATE:** the issues does not reproduce with "CDN" style. Here's the perfectly working JSBin: https://jsbin.com/ziqasifoli/edit?html,js,output

It looks that it is connected to something amongst webpack/gulf/elixir/vuefy.. I.e., all that Laravel 5.3 infrastructure. Not sure even where to start debugging.

...

I'm struggling with a simple (as I thought) component, that gets `name`, `options` and `selected` as input and displays multiple selectbox:

```
<!-- TagSelector.vue: -->

<template>
    <select :name="name" v-model="selected" multiple>
      <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      props: ['name', 'options', 'selected'],
    }
</script>
```

.

```
// app.js

Vue.component('tags-selector', require('./components/form_fields/TagsSelector.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

.

```
<!-- some.form.blade.php -->

<tags-selector
  class="form-control"
  name="posted_data[tags]"
  :selected="['opt1', 'opt2']"
  :options='{!! json_encode($options) !!}'
></tags-selector>
```

It displays selector as expected, but no options pre-selected there.
How do I get it working?

Comment: please provide JSBin or similar.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/ziqasifoli/edit?html,js,output
Here I don't use modules and/or vuefy kind of stuff and it actually works well. So, now need to figure out what's wrong with "laravel-style" vuefying...

Answer (score 1):

To set some options as selected by default you will want to bind them to data, to do this simply make a copy of your `selected` prop and use `v-model` to bind it, which you can do with the created hook:

```
  created: function() {
    this.selectedCopy = this.selected;
  },
  data: function(){
    return {
      selectedCopy: []
    }
  }
```

Then simply bind them by using v-model:

```
<select :name="name" v-model="selectedCopy" multiple>
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3cq1jjL8/

Comment: I think I may have overcomplicated my last answer, I've now re-read your question and updated my answer for you.

Comment: Than you. It turns out, however, that my original code (with just "properties") is perfectly working when you use CDN to load Vue. There are issues somewhere else... Check my question updated.